# How to bind datatable to gridview with five row per column

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

dgmain.columncount = 5;

dgmain.DataSource = dt;
dgmain.DataBind();
```

---

example:  column1 column2 column3 ...

```
      data     data     data

      data     data     data

      data     data     data
```

---

I am looking for property/event something like the bold word.
Could anyone help?

What I trying to do is, I have one set of data(775 rows)in one column, but I want to rearrange data with every 5 row in each column in the GridView.

Comment: add Top 5 in your select statement

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to do this cause i am already query out these data, and i dont know how to put into each column like '5,5,5,5,...'

Comment: select top 5  column1 column2 column3 from yourTable

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with DataList instead of using a GridView by using it's RepeatColumns property

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
```

Here's an example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525467.aspx

Hope this is what you are after.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);
```

Comment: @user3054801 Similar to what Damith showed in his answer.